# avconv file protocol with rw_timeout and follow

Tags: avconv

I use avconv to convert a webm (still being recorded while converting) to h264.
I want avconv to wait while being written to the file.

https://libav.org/avconv.html#file says I can use the follow and rw_timeout option.
But when I use them with avconv 11.7 I always get the unregonized option response.

```
avconv  -y -follow 1 -i file:/tmp/video/krtv/5405457303486272/recordings/video.webm -s hd720 -r 15 -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -c:a aac /tmp/video/krtv/5405457303486272/sized/video.mp4
avconv version 11.7, Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 29 2016 10:40:47 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
Unrecognized option 'follow'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

How to use these options on the file protocol with avconv 11.7?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be version 11.7 does not support this.
Compiling 12.alpha1 fixed this issue